# Xcode 13: Headers of Imported Frameworks Inaccessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, xcode13

I am having trouble with Xcode referencing header files from imported frameworks. The strange thing is that everything worked fine yesterday. But now, I cannot even import the same headers I see one line above that do not give me a compiler error.

You can see in the image below that the compiler is fine with "Ironsource/Ironsource.h" but when I'm trying to add it again it doesn't know what it is (but it did yesterday):

[image]

It is not a localized problem to one Xcode project, Xcode cannot see header files in any of my projects. Or more precisely, Xcode cannot see any **NEW** header files I would like to import but has no problem with the ones imported a day before. So, I am guessing it is something with Xcode, but I cannot figure out what went wrong.

Also, it doesn't matter if I try to reference headers in:

- .framework
- .xcframework

files.

The frameworks were added manually in the Project Navigator and can be seen properly in Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

[image]

I am using Xcode 13.3.1. and my project and used frameworks are both pure Objective C. I have both restarted Xcode and my Mac multiple times but they didn't help.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Framework headers are usually imported with angular brackets "<>". If you use quotes the compiler would search in the User header search paths in which case you would need to add the relevant path to User header search paths. Also make sure to make the header public if you use angled brackets.